# Error while sending a build of parse4cn1 application for device

Tags: parse-platform, codenameone, parse4j, parse4cn1

I am experiencing some problems building for iOS (Debug).

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new CN1 project. Send iOS build -> no errors.
- Drag parse4cn1.cn1lib into the lib folder -> iOS build fails with "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/moe/ibuddy2/iBuddyApplication : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0".
- Some googling reveals that this may mean that JDK 1.8 isn't supported. Therefore, I edit build.xml, replacing "1.8" with "1.7" everywhere.
- When I send the iOS build now, the error message is "/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build2564350766160402235xxx/dist/iBuddyApplication-src/com_parse4cn1_nativeinterface_Utils.m:3:9: fatal error: 'com_parse4cn1_ParsePush.h' file not found"

There are no problems running the simulator or building for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the JDK version (so please don't change it in build.xml). I think the actual issue is the 'file not found' error which is caused by stripping out of unused classes/methods by the CN1 build server. In this case, ParsePush is detected as a false positive (because it is actually used in the iOS native code and should not be stripped out).

The problem has been fixed in parse4cn1 version 2.0.1 which is available on [github](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/releases/tag/parse4cn1-2.0.1). Please try with that version.